# After checking a tax audit, Massachusetts is owing me some money: what interest should I claim?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, interest, massachusetts, audit

I got audited by the state of Massachusetts, USA, due to a mistake I did when filing my [2015 Form 1](https://www.mass.gov/lists/2015-massachusetts-personal-income-tax-forms-and-instructions) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180919085428/https://www.mass.gov/files/documents/2017/12/04/dor-2015-inc-form-1_0.pdf)). The audit's conclusion was that I have to pay some amount to Massachusetts, which includes some interest (15.124314442%).

After fixing the mistake, it turns out that Massachusetts is actually owing me money (the tax refund as mentioned on line 46 in Form 1 is higher than  what I reported when I first filed form 1 in 2016). What interest can I claim on it? Do I use the same interest rate as they used? Or perhaps I am not entitled to any interest since I made the reporting mistake?

Comment: https://www.mass.gov/info-details/refunds-and-credit-of-overpayments#interest-calculation-and-rates-from-a-refund-of-an-overpayment-of-tax-claimed-on-a-return- seems to say that they would not pay you any interest unless it takes them more than 90 days to process your amended return and send you a refund.  And even if it takes more than 90 days, they only owe you interest from the filing date of your amended return (not your original return).  But the wording is not entirely clear, so I'm not 100% certain of this.